# PageSpeed Insights - in English

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am located in Spain, but my OS, browser settings and all on my laptop is in English.
For some reason, PageSpeed Insights appears in Spanish, which I don't want. When I change the language settings for PageSpeed Insights https://www.screencast.com/t/oh940PDu2ec then it reverts back to Spanish.
What can I do please?
Thanks!!!

Comment: how are you changing the language settings? What is your query string?

Comment: I am changing the language settings with the standard language button at the top right. See screenshot please:  https://www.screencast.com/t/oh940PDu2ec     I am not sure what you mean with query string but the URL of the page to change the language looks like this:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/languages
and the URL of the Pagespeed test look like this:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wildswimmingholes.com%2F
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 13):

The language setting in the top right of the documentation section doesn't change your report language, only the documentation language. You need to click the language in the list itself which will take you to the correct Page Speed Insights language variation.

All this does is change the URL to have `?hl=es` (for example) at the end where `es` is for Spanish (so for your needs you would want `?hl=en` to force the page to English.)

You can then save the url `https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en` as a bookmark and run your report from there and it will always be in English.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much Graham!!

Comment: Not an issue, glad it helped! You can press the tick to mark the answer as accepted just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, if the answer above didn't work, try to change your browser's preferred language settings. In Chrome, you can go to `chrome://settings/languages` then open the **Language** accordion, then update it.

After that, force refresh the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: Chrome Language Settings Page]

Comment: Didn't knew this setting existed, now I can have English as default all on websites (almost).